# App all messed up with 'ant release'

Tags: android

I've been building my app just fine in intellij. Now I want to publish my app. I ran ant release and signed my app. Seemed to build just fine. Then I installed it and notices all of the colors are messed up, drawables are using the wrong ones, etc. The way I created the build.xml to run ant release was with `android update project --target 10 --path /mypath` This enabled me to build with ant (note intellij wasnt using ant).

If it helps, heres the build.xml that the above command produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Main" default="help">

    <!-- The local.properties file is created and updated by the 'android' tool.
         It contains the path to the SDK. It should *NOT* be checked into
         Version Control Systems. -->
    <loadproperties srcFile="local.properties" />

    <!-- The ant.properties file can be created by you. It is only edited by the
         'android' tool to add properties to it.
         This is the place to change some Ant specific build properties.
         Here are some properties you may want to change/update:

         source.dir
             The name of the source directory. Default is 'src'.
         out.dir
             The name of the output directory. Default is 'bin'.

         For other overridable properties, look at the beginning of the rules
         files in the SDK, at tools/ant/build.xml

         Properties related to the SDK location or the project target should
         be updated using the 'android' tool with the 'update' action.

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems.

         -->
    <property file="ant.properties" />

    <!-- The project.properties file is created and updated by the 'android'
         tool, as well as ADT.

         This contains project specific properties such as project target, and library
         dependencies. Lower level build properties are stored in ant.properties
         (or in .classpath for Eclipse projects).

         This file is an integral part of the build system for your
         application and should be checked into Version Control Systems. -->
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

    <!-- quick check on sdk.dir -->
    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project'"
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />


<!-- extension targets. Uncomment the ones where you want to do custom work
     in between standard targets -->
<!--
    <target name="-pre-build">
    </target>
    <target name="-pre-compile">
    </target>

    /* This is typically used for code obfuscation.
       Compiled code location: ${out.classes.absolute.dir}
       If this is not done in place, override ${out.dex.input.absolute.dir} */
    <target name="-post-compile">
    </target>
-->

    <!-- Import the actual build file.

         To customize existing targets, there are two options:
         - Customize only one target:
             - copy/paste the target into this file, *before* the
               <import> task.
             - customize it to your needs.
         - Customize the whole content of build.xml
             - copy/paste the content of the rules files (minus the top node)
               into this file, replacing the <import> task.
             - customize to your needs.

         ***********************
         ****** IMPORTANT ******
         ***********************
         In all cases you must update the value of version-tag below to read 'custom' instead of an integer,
         in order to avoid having your file be overridden by tools such as "android update project"
    -->
    <!-- version-tag: 1 -->
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

</project>
```

If the above seems messed up to you, can you show me what my build.xml should like or tell me how I can generate a usable one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to include any dependencies (form other android projects) in project.properties and jars other than in libs folder.

Comment: Could you explain that a little bit? do I have to manually write external libraries to project.properties and the use the ant release?